# Akka scheduler not completing

Tags: scala, akka, scheduler, actor

I need to send a message to an actor at specific intervals. I am using the following code:

```
object SendToActor extends App {

  import Sender._

  val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("sender")

  try {
    val senderActor: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Sender.props, "sendActor")
    val sendSchedule =
      system.scheduler.schedule(0 milliseconds, 5 minutes, senderActor, doSomething())
  } finally {
    system.terminate()
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the scheduler doesn't seem to run unless I do one of the following:

1. Put a `readLine()` right after it:

   ```
   val sendSchedule = system.scheduler.schedule(0 milliseconds, 5 minutes, senderActor, doSomething())
   readLine()
   ```
2. Put a `Thread.sleep()` right after it:

   ```
   val sendSchedule = system.scheduler.schedule(0 milliseconds, 5 minutes, senderActor, doSomething())
   Thread.sleep(10000)
   ```

Is there a reason why the scheduler won't run as coded above? Why does it require the sleep in order to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because you're terminating the actor system immediately after defining the scheduler.

Comment: Makes sense. I remove the system.terminate() and I see the process. But shouldn't the try block stay alive until the scheduled task finishes?.Thanks

Comment: No @F.Lun, the `system.scheduler.schedule` return immediately and do not block the caller.